# Mouthwash on a public fast day?

Tags: halacha, fast-days, health-safety-shmira, cleaning, personal-hygiene

Is it permitted to use mouthwash on a public fast day? Would a sensitive mouth, due to medical reasons be a good reason to be lenient?

(I can see it being less problematic than brushing one's teeth, because there's no fresh water being used, only the chemical mix that is mouthwash; that's not something you'd drink.)

Comment: @sethJ is Yom Kippur not a public fast day?

Comment: @double aa, not as usually defined. I still remember getting that wrong in 4th grade.

Comment: @SethJ Tisha b'Av too? Where have you seen the term so defined?

Comment: @double aa in any event, it doesn't change the intent, and it matches the accepted answer.

Comment: related: [Listerine strips on Yom Kippur and Pesach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28648/11501) and [Is one allowed to brush teeth on yom kippur with toothpaste without any water?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64114/11501)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Per [Mishna Berura Orach Chaim 567:3:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=87&hilite=) if a person is bothered by the lack of brushing their teeth or the smell/taste in their mouth, they are permitted to rinse their mouth on public fasts, however one should tip their head forward in order that it should not reach their throat.

Comment: Gershon, since the problem is "he may swallow it", I'm not sure how your answer covers Moshe's 2nd point, which should circumvent the issue.

Comment: This answer covers all points. It is allowed even for a non sensitive mouth.

Comment: The MB (who is referring to water) has 2 prerequisites:  1. He has "tzaar".  2. He tilts his head forward.  (Note: The Aruch haShulchan only requires #2.) I think there is room in the case of mouthwash to negate both prerequisites since it is not an edible product.

Comment: @YDK, that sounds reasonable, but you need a source, which is what I think Moshe is looking for.

Comment: @SethJ, Yes, I was just bringing out Moshe's question, not try to answer it.

Comment: _...."and on Yom Kippur one should be stringent in [not doing] this"_

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13020/11501) on this page covers fast days in general but is not specific to Yom Kippur. On Yom Kippur specifically, *poskim* prohibit using mouthwash.

dinonline [writes](https://dinonline.org/2011/02/09/rinsing-mouth-on-fasts/) (see original for sources)

> It is permitted to rinse one’s mouth with mouthwash, **with the
>   exception of Yom Kippur, when it is prohibited**.

R David Katz (author of [Kesser Dovid: Halachic Guide To Dentistry](https://www.feldheim.com/kesser-dovid-halachic-guide-to-dentistry.html)) [writes](https://www.jewishpress.com/indepth/interviews-and-profiles/when-dentistry-meets-halacha-an-interview-with-rabbi-dr-david-katz/2018/01/03/)

> The potential violation would be tasting on a fast day, but the
>   Achronim tend to be meikel **on fast days other than Yom Kippur**

R Eliezer Melamed (author of Peninei Halacha) [writes](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/05-07-05/) (see original for sources)

> On Yom Kippur, however, when one must fast according to Torah law, **one
>   should not be lenient**.

The only lenient opening I found was R Chaim Tabasky on yeshiva.co.il ([here](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/2521)) but I don't understand it

> One is not allowed to rinse one's mouth with water or mouthwash on Yom
>   Kippur. However, if you will find it very uncomfortable to fast and
>   pray, and you add something to the mouthwash to make its taste
>   unpalatable, it is allowed.

Of course, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).