# Tevila on mouthwash cup

Tags: halacha, tevilas-keilim-dipping, cleaning

In some people's sink area they keep a glass or metal cup to wash their mouth out after they brush their teeth. Must one Tovel that cup even though they don't swallow the water/liquid? Plus, even if one does swallow, it is accidental.

CYLOR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [OU](http://www.oukosher.org/index.php/passover/_print_article/tevilatkeilim) has the following on their website.

> Secondly, the determination of tevilah depends on the owner's
>   designated use for the object: a utensil purchased for non-food
>   purposes and occasionally used to hold food (such as a screwdriver
>   which might be used in a pinch in the absence of a fork) does not
>   require tevilah (Aruch Hashulchan, Y.D. 120:40)

I would say a mouthwash cup is being used for non food purposes and does not need to be Toiveled.

Comment: Is washing one's mouth considered non-food? What about fasting?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13014/mouthwash-on-a-fast-day