# Listerine strips on Yom Kippur and Pesach

Tags: passover, fast-days, yom-kippur

I heard recently in the name of Rav Hershel Schachter that you can consume Listerine strips (such as [these](http://www.listerine.com/products/pocket-paks-oral-care-strips)) on both Yom Kippur and Pesach without worry.

I wonder if anyone can confirm this, and explain to me why and how it would be okay? It'd sure change my Yom Kippur...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can listen to him discuss it [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?lxmmy2nfj11) at 56:12. He says it isn't *rau'i l'achilat adam* (fit for human consumption) so it isn't considered eating. He quotes some opinions that it is a problem of washing the inside of the mouth on Yom Kippur, but he doesn't seem so impressed by the idea.

Comment: See the other answer. I don't know when the recording I linked to is from.

Answer (score 4):

I was just recently asked this shaila, so I told the shoel to contact Rav Shachter directly. Here's what happened:
"After trying a few times I finally got through. He was very nice and patient!
He said that years back the Listerine strips had no flavor and tasted awful in which case there might be a heter, however these days the Listerine strips have flavor and it’s for sure assur because people actually have benefit from the flavor."

Comment: Well done for encouraging an enquiry.