# Is one allowed to brush teeth on yom kippur with toothpaste without any water?

Tags: halacha, medicine, yom-kippur, ashkenazi, personal-hygiene

Is one allowed to brush teeth on Yom Kippur with toothpaste on a toothbrush without rinsing toothbrush before and without rinsing mouth after? What if its prescription which I would think probably makes it more dangerous to swallow? (Also would there be a difference between flavors sweet vs mint?)

On kashrut.org which is based on Rabbi Abadi it's allowed but everywhere else they say it's not/not recommended. Does anyone know of any Ashkenazic sources/poskim that allow it?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28648/1713

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, to [enable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. While you're at it, I suggest that you [edit your profile](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) and give yourself a name! Gemar chatima tova.

Comment: I think it has everything to do with turning a solid into a liquid. The toothpaste is solid-like to start but by the end it's water-like.

Comment: What @ezra seems to refer to is a problem of *memarech* - "smearing" which may be problematic with most toothpastes. The ones that are a soft gel **may** not be a problem.

Comment: @DanF That is exactly what I mean

Comment: Other than the possible melacha that ezra alluded to, there doesn't seem to be a problem of *achila* (eating) as you don't eat toothpaste. However, IIRC, I think there is general consensus against even putting a taste in one's mouth on Yom Kippur. Thus, by similar idea, this would forbid chewing gum.